# Google Maps - A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I want to implement Google Map in my Android app, I just follow the Google Maps Platform instruction, but it didn't work. I don't know why meta-data does not exist while I already declare it in the manifest:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity android:name="some.Activity"></activity>


        <meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
</application>
```

local.properties

```
MAPS_API_KEY=HereIsTheSecretAPIstored
```

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.5'
}
```

service maps version:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1"
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:17)
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

After some efforts, finally, I able to solve the problem with this solution:

1. Change meta-data and move to the top of activity tag.

From

```
<meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

To

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

2 Also, I forgot to enable Maps SDK for Android in Google Console, so I enable it.

Comment: Does this belong under application level then?